# List files on FTPServer recursively

Tags: android, list, file, ftp

I want my App to list all directories and files on my FTP-Server. This is the code from [How to list ftp directories with android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180514/how-to-list-ftp-directories-with-android):

```
FTPFile[] files = null;
files = ftpClient.listDirectories();
String path = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
       path = files[0].getName();
       Log.d("CONNECT", "Directories: "+ files[i].getName());
    }

    FTPFile[] files2 = ftpClient.listFiles(topPath);
    for (int j = 0; j < files2.length; j++) {
    Log.d("CONNECT", "Below " + files[j].getName()
                            + " is " + files2[j].getName());
    }

}
```

Now this works for only for the first two layers. How can I manage to get as deep as necessary so I can list files that in folders that are in folders that are in folders and so on?

Thanks in advance :)

Now what I tried (not quite) recursively:

```
{ ...
FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles();
listContent(files);
.... }
private void listContent(FTPFile[] file) throws IOException {

        FTPFile[] list = ftpClient.listDirectories();
        if (list != null) {
            for (FTPFile f : list) {
                if (f.isDirectory()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "directory: " + f.getName());
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "file: " + f.getName());
                }
            }
            listContent(list);
        } else return;

    }
```

This code lets me get just the first layer of directories, the FTPFile[] is overwritten in ever new cycle. 
How can I do that?

UPDATE:
Here's my solution. This code walks the whole content of the host-adress. Thanks to all who helped me:

```
private void listContent(String s) throws IOException {

        try {
            FTPFile[] ftpFiles = ftpClient.listFiles(s);
            int length = ftpFiles.length;

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                String name = ftpFiles[i].getName();
                boolean isFile = ftpFiles[i].isFile();

                if (isFile) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "File : " + name);
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Directory : " + name);

                    if (ftpChangeDirectory(name) == true) {
                        Log.d("ftpChangeDirectory", name);
                        String newDir = ftpGetCurrentWorkingDirectory();
                        Log.d(TAG, "new Dir: " + newDir);
                        listContent(newDir);
                    }
                }
            }
            ftpChangeDirectory("..");
            String test = ftpGetCurrentWorkingDirectory();
            Log.d("dirUp", test);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Then you have to make it recursive.

Comment: Sure, but how... Edit: Sorry, forgot to post my recursive code... just a minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test it but something like this should work :

```
private void listAllFiles(String path) // path is the top folder to start the search
{
    FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles(path); // Search all the files in the current directory
    for (int j = 0; j < files.length; j++) {
        Log.d("CONNECT", "Files: " + files[j].getName()); // Print the name of each files
    }

    FTPFile[] directories = ftpClient.listDirectories(path); // Search all the directories in the current directory

    for (int i = 0; i < directories.length; i++) {
        String dirPath = directories[i].getName();
        Log.d("CONNECT", "Directories: "+ dirPath); // Print the path of a sub-directory

        listAllFiles(dirPath); // Call recursively the method to display the files in the sub-directory
    }
}
```

Anyway, i strongly recommend that you understand the code and check this [link](http://danzig.jct.ac.il/java_class/recursion.html) to learn more about recursivity.

Comment: The problem is that you can only reach the top folder of an FTP-Server by comitting a string. To get all the data below, you have to iterate through the FTPFile[]. And that is my problem. I just can't find a way to do that without overwriting the FTPFile[]  with every recursion. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Hmm, i don't understand the problem here. From the [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) i can't see why it wouldn't work. Have you try my code ? What's the error ?

Comment: The program doesn't fill FTPFile[] files. It leaves the method after FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles(path). Could the problem be, that I need  log in for the server (what I of course do when connecting)? (Anyways, a path like "ftp://userID:password@anyadress" can't be resolved when comitted as a parameter.)

Comment: Check this [link](http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=28%5D) to see how you can connect to a FTP server. You can call my method with a path like this: `listAllFiles("path/folder")`.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that's the solution. The "ftpChangeDirectory(String directory_path)" method is the key! :)